# У тебя совсем другие обязанности, не то(,) что у меня

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Как правильно пунктуационно оформить такое предложение:

> У тебя другие обязанности, не то(,) что у меня!

Нужна ли обозначенная запятая? Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Нужна ли обозначенная запятая?

НЕ НУЖНА. (Вместо первой запятой возможно тире.)

> [**НЕ ТО ЧТО**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_491), союз
>
> Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «не то что» выделяются знаками
>   препинания, обычно запятыми. Между частями союза знак препинания не
>   ставится.
>
> *Только и накостыляют-то несильно, потому что пароходами публика плавает все больше культурная, деликатная, **не то что** в приречных
>   селах.* Б. Акунин, Пелагия и красный петух.
>
> *Но Эктов все более укреплялся в том, что не требует никакого оправдания повседневная помощь крестьянину в его текущих насущных
>   нуждах, облегчение народной нужды в любой реальной форме – **не то
>   что** в отвлекающей проповеди сельских батюшек и твердилке
>   церковно-приходских школ.* А. Солженицын, Два рассказа.

Comment: Как объяснить запятую в "не то, что нынешнее племя" (пока попадается только такой вариант текста)? Нерушимый союз "не то что", конечно же, есть ("не то что красную, а и чёрную икру есть не желает"), но на все ли случаи жизни он един в своей нерушимости?

Comment: Гм... Поставили Вы меня в тупик! Постараюсь поискать ответ. "Не то, что нынешнее племя" с запятой встречается и в учебниках Розенталя. И всё же, как показывает Гугл, некоторые современные авторы при цитировании этих лермонтовских строк запятую перед "что" предпочитают опустить.